# Error using FragmentActivity, Activity and SherlockActivity - Android

Tags: android, class, listview, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying to implement a listview in my application for a while now and I am using actionbarsherlock. I have had this android.support.v4.Fragment error for a while now and this is what needs fixing/ I know I have to use something from actionbarsherlock but I am unsure what as I have tried FragmentActivity, Activity and SherlockActivity to get it to run. The CustomizedListView.class is where the ListView is located and the other classes that are part of the tab system work fine. Here is the logcat:

```
07-20 09:21:01.673    1389-1389/com.example.release E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 09:21:01.869    1389-1389/com.example.release E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.release.CustomizedListView         cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
    at com.example.release.TabSwipe.getItem(TabSwipe.java:98)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:979)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have code for tabs in my MainActivity.class which is probably causing it and it is probably because I forgot to do something like a fragment.

MainActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabSwipe mTabSwipe;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabSwipe = new TabSwipe(this, mViewPager);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("This"), CustomizedListView.class, null);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("That"), Purchase_Fragment.class, null);
    mTabSwipe.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Null"), Purchase_Fragment.class, null);


    }
}
```

CustomizedListView.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `CustomizedListView` should extend `Fragment` and not `Activity` because `mtabwipe.addtab(...)` expects a fragment